# Oracle Error ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-29259: end-of-input reached When Calling UTL_HTTP.request

Tags: oracle, api, https, oracle12c

I am trying to call a web service using the Oracle `UTL_HTTP.request` API. The call requires a proxy & wallet/certificate. I believe I have cleared up the certificate issues, since I no longer get a `ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure` error. Now I am getting `ORA-29259: end-of-input reached` error. I am using DBMS version 12.1.0.2.0, and should be using TLS 1.2 (not sure how to verify this).

The following call works perfectly & returns a JSON payload:

```
SELECT utl_http.request (
  'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  'proxy.myurl.com')
FROM dual;
```

Response:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

The following call throws the ORA-29259 error:

```
SELECT utl_http.request (
  'https://service.baseurl.com/ping',
  'proxy.myurl.com',
  'file:/my/wallet/location',
  'mypassword'
 )
FROM DUAL;
```

Runtime exception stack:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29259: end-of-input reached
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1491
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I have also tried calling `UTL_HTTP.begin_request` using an anonymous PL/SQL block, but get essentially the same `ORA-29259` error as above.

```
DECLARE
  l_http_request utl_http.req;
  l_http_response utl_http.resp;
  l_text VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  utl_http.set_proxy('proxy.myurl.com');
  utl_http.set_wallet('file:/my/wallet/location'
                      ,'mypassword');
  l_http_request := utl_http.begin_request('https://service.baseurl.com/ping' 
                                           ,'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
  l_http_response := utl_http.get_response(l_http_request);
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      utl_http.read_text(l_http_response, l_text, 32766);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_text);
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION WHEN utl_http.end_of_body THEN
    utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);
  END;
END;

ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29259: end-of-input reached
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1258
ORA-06512: at line 10
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this error?

Comment: Have you configured an ACL for the wallet? See [MoS document ID 2303905](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2303905.1)

Comment: I tried running the `DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_WALLET_ACE` code as `SYSTEM` for privileges `'use_client_certificates', 'use_passwords'`. It completed without error, but I am still getting the same `ORA-29259` error when calling `UTL_HTTP.request`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem would be the missing cipher suits in 12.1c.
You have to apply a on your database, security patch 24666032 and the minimum DBBP should be 12.1.0.2.160719 (23054246).

After that, the database should add support for cipher.

You can view this information on MOS:UTL_HTTP access to secured website fails with ORA-29259 in 12c database (Doc ID 2402276.1)

Regards

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the database is at PSU 12.1.0.2.160419. I'll try to get it patched up & see if that works.

Comment: I think it will, but I have to wait until we migrate our environment to new hosting before applying patches.