# utl_http GET request to REST API fails with ORA-29273: HTTP request failed

Tags: oracle

I am trying to make a `GET` request to the [International Space station REST API](https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544) as a test from PLSQL, but it is giving me a `ORA-29273: HTTP request failed` error.

My code is this:

```
declare
l_url            varchar2(32767) := 'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544';
l_http_request   utl_http.req;
l_http_response  utl_http.resp;
l_text           varchar2(32767);
begin
  -- Make a HTTP request and get the response.
  l_http_request := utl_http.begin_request(l_url);
  -- Use basic authentication if required.
  --IF p_username IS NOT NULL and p_password IS NOT NULL THEN
  --  UTL_HTTP.set_authentication(l_http_request, p_username, p_password);
  --END IF;
  l_http_response := utl_http.get_response(l_http_request);
  -- Loop through the response.
  begin
    loop
      utl_http.read_text(l_http_response, l_text, 32766);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_text);
    end loop;
  exception
    when utl_http.end_of_body then
      utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);
  end;
exception
  when others then
    utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);
    raise;
end;
```

And the error is this:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at line 27
ORA-29259: end-of-input reached
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1148
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

Anybody know what the problem is or how to correctly make a `GET` request to a REST API endpoint url?

Comment: have you tried with `apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
  p_url => 'your url',  p_http_method => 'GET'
);` It is much better and the output is json . You only have to setup the ACL in order for the database to handle the request. Same for your utl_http, you need privileges in the ACL.

Comment: do you have a proxy between your database and internet ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you check to check to see if you have allowed this API host through ACL.
That may be your problem.
https://ittutorial.org/oracle-acl-the-access-control-list-acl-and-how-to-create-and-grant-an-acl-in-oracle-database/

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer. You should use the comment section for this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The `ORA-29259: end-of-input reached` error usually indicates that UTL_HTTP failed to negotiate the security for an HTTPS connection. You can find several [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368580/oracle-error-ora-29273-http-request-failed-ora-29259-end-of-input-reached-when) on here - sometimes it means that your Oracle version doesn't support the cipher suite that the HTTPS server requires, but in your case I think it might mean that you haven't set up a wallet yet.

There are several steps involved to do HTTPS/SSL connections from Oracle database.

You need to [create an Oracle wallet with the site certificates](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl) for the HTTPS site you're trying to reach.

You also need to set up ACLs, which the link above [mentions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-11gr1).